# mysql limit for special column

Tags: mysql, limit

Hi I want to limit my SQL query but if I Limit it, it all is mixed up and I don't know what value it takes to limit. Is it possible to limit it to a special column?

```
$sql = "SELECT number1.number1, number2.number2, number3.number3 from number1,
         number2, number3 LIMIT $_SESSION[startwert],$_SESSION[zielwert]";
$qry = mysql_query($sql,$db);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no `ORDER BY` clause is specified then `LIMIT` will retrieve the rows in the same order as they were stored if you do not wish this you can add a `ORDER BY` clause before the `LIMIT`

Like:

```
SELECT 
  number1.number1, 
  number2.number2, 
  number3.number3 
FROM 
  number1, 
  number2, 
  number3 
ORDER BY
  number1.number1, 
  number2.number2, 
  number3.number3 
LIMIT 
  $_SESSION[startwert],$_SESSION[zielwert]
```

Comment: Must I enter a value for ORDER BY? For example ORDER BY number3?

Comment: yes, you need to specify after what column(s) you want to order. you can read more here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: Must I do all ORDER BY? I have tried it with one but I get an error.

Comment: Ok I have tried all and also get an error... other solutions? I get this error  Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_e76_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Comment: whats the exact query are you using?

Comment: Like this above.

I have tried:
SELECT number1.number1, number2.number2, number3.number3 from number1, number2, number3 ORDER BY number3 LIMIT 0,1

The query without "ORDER BY" works normal.

Comment: sorry my bad ... since the column name is the same with the table you need to specify `table.column` I've updated the query pls try now

Comment: Ok i tried SELECT number1.number1, number2.number2, number3.number3 from number1, number2, number3 ORDER BY number3.number3 LIMIT 0,1 and get this #126 - Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_174f_0.MYI'; try to repair it. Can it be that the query is too big? I think in every table are 10.000-40.000 Entrys. hmm... but without ORDER BY it works...

Comment: man pls look at my query its has `ORDER BY
  number1.number1, 
  number2.number2, 
  number3.number3 `

Comment: I tried this also (SELECT number1.number1, number2.number2, number3.number3 from number3, number1, number2 ORDER BY number3.number3, number1.number1, number2.number2  LIMIT 0,1)... self error.

Comment: ok ... then its another issue please run `REPAIR` and `OPTIMIZE` on all 3 tables

Comment: hmm.. please check if you have free space on the `/tmp` partition

Comment: you can read this maybe it will help http://www.mysqlperformancetuning.com/a-fix-for-incorrect-key-file-for-table-mysql